# How can ignore null value in spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

if deletedAt is null ignore it, like use `findById`,if not null use `findByIdAndDeletedAt`,if in more and more properties, it's a trouble.how can i do?like `IgnoreCase` custom `IgnoreNull` and `AllIgnoreNull`?

```
public interface AreaRepository extends CommonJpaRepository<AreaEntity, Integer> {

  AreaEntity findByIdAndDeletedAtIgnoreNull(Integer id,Date deletedAt);
 }
```

like this,

```
if (review.getDeletedAt() != null){
   query.addCriteria(new Criteria("deletedAt").is(review.getDeletedAt()));
}
```

but I do not want to write this for every table,so hope to write `IgnoreNull` key word with spring data.

Comment: I would simply use two different methods, and choose the appropriate one. But you can also define a custom repository method where you would construct your own JPQL query, or use the criteria API.

Comment: This requires a lot of code to write, I do not think this is a good solution，I want resolve it for all developer.can custom keyword?

Comment: I have not tried this but what if you change it to
`findByIdAndDeletedAtIsNotNullAndDeletedAt

Comment: @ismoore999  it terrible  for more than 10+ arguments, and that mean must  add `deletedAt is not null` in where condition,I need remove this term.

Comment: Actually I realise my answer was a little stupid but then your question is also wrong.

Comment: Generally in DB terms, saying `deletedAt = null` will never equate to anything so I would have thought this is not an issue anyway. Have you tried to see what SQL is produced?
Otherwise you will have to code around this as there is nothing that will fulfill your complex requirement

Comment: yes,I found `IgnoreCase`,so I want write something like this with keyword `IgnoreNull`,but I don't know  how to write code to solve it. could you help me ? @ismoore999

Comment: Your mean when param null you want to ignore.
Maybe you can see this.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209